# How to insert an item to array

Tags: java, arraylist

Like title. I wanna add an item to an Array List. For example, I had:

```
List<String> saveData = new ArrayList();
```

and,

```
 String dataF = "something";
 saveData.add(0,dataF);
```

I think, it's correct code to insert 'dataF' to position'0'. And, I add more than one dataF to position '0'. But, when I try to Log data of saveData, I only find data of position '0'. I get:

```
  for (int i=0;i<saveData.size();i++){
     Log.i(TAG_LOG,"S Show data: "+saveData.get(i));
  }

  S Show data: c-5-8-8-8-8-true
```

and other position, it's empty. Hope some once can help me or give a solution.
UPDATE: I fixed thanks guys

Comment: better to try using for each loop

Comment: yeah. but, i want put data from keyboard. So its not help in this case

Comment: @Gaurav what do you mean? The API clearly stated out that the elements will be shift and not deleted: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)

Answer (score 1):

You see data of position 0 because you are saving data only to position 0.

Below is the correct method to add data to a list:

```
  List al = new ArrayList();
  al.add(0,"Zara");
  al.add(1,"Mahnaz");
  al.add(2,"Ayan");      
  System.out.println("The elements are :");
  System.out.print("\t" + a1);
```

**Remember** the first parameter is optional in `a1.add(0,"Zara");`

I would suggest you skip the first parameter.

Reference:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_list_interface.htm

Comment: Sr, because my question not clearly, I mean, i want put 'new dataF- an item' to position 0 and push item in position 0 to position 1. I try to use ArrayList but is not help

Comment: @AkiNoKo So you want to do `al.add(0,"Zara");` and move "Zara" to position 0 ?

Comment: @Aki No Ko: What Shakti said is correct. The method `add(0,"Zara)` add the element to position 0 and shifts all elements one position to the next. So, that element that has been on position 0 is now on position 1 automatically. So your issue must anywhere else...

Comment: @Aki No Ko : please post the complete class. My guess is, that you allways create a new ArrayList at the wrong point....

Comment: like that. i want 1 string in position 0 call Zara, and when i add new string in position 0 call Zara_1. Zara go to position 1. And repeat like that, Zara_2, Zara_3,... I will put in position 0(always). Zara_? in position 0 will go to position next (1). like that. hope you understand my idea

Comment: That´s what I told ya....the method add(position,element) is exactly what you need. Like I said, your issue is anywhere else and we just can help if we see your class...

Comment: I agree with @opiatefuchs

Answer (score 0):

try this to create array list like this

```
final ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

    name.add("1");
    name.add("2");
    name.add("3");
    name.add("4");
    name.add("5");
    name.add("6");
    name.add("7");
    name.add("8");
```

and add elements like this

```
 final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name.add(0, editText.getText().toString().trim());
            for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++){
                Log.e("Val :-> ",name.get(i));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sr, because my question not clearly, I mean, i want put 'new dataF- an item' to position 0 and push item in position 0 to position 1. I try to use ArrayList but is not help. Beside that, i wanna input data from keyboard.

Comment: @AkiNoKo check my ans and ask me in case of any query

Answer (score 0):

If you push newData to position 0, alway value in pos 0 come to pos 1

```
List<String> saveData = new ArrayList(); 

    saveData.add(0,"0");
    saveData.add(0,"1");


    for(String a : saveData){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Result is `1 0`

Comment: yeah, it's absolute what i want ask. but, problem is add function not work in my case. p.s: you using kotlin ? cool

Comment: @Aki No Ko.....Is there a reason why you don´t want to post more of your project? I am really sure (like my comments on Shakti´s answer), that your issue is another.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs sr, but i don't think so. i mean, i used ArrayList an List just for 1 purpose, when i save something to position 0, this will push the item in position 0 to position 1. just it

Comment: #ok but I bet your issue is anywhere else. The method is exactly what you need

Comment: Additional: "i used ArrayList just for 1 purpose"....if this use is a repeating use, let´s say a method that you call mor than once, the arrayList will always be initialized again and everything is lost.